# jquery store variable class (performance)

Tags: jquery, class, variables

I want to know what is the best way in term of performances to store variables for classes.
I mean is it better to store one div id than to find all other class name thanks to children() function. Or is it better to write the class name in the variable?

for example like this:

```
var $innerDiv = $('#inner-container'),
    $customSlider = $('#custom-slider'),
    $customSliderInner = $customSlider.children().first(),
    $customSliderTimer = $customSliderInner.next().next().next().next(),
    $customSliderButtonLeft = $customSliderInner.next(), 
    $customSliderButtonRight = $customSliderInner.next().next(), 
    $customSliderLeft = $customSliderButtonLeft.children().first(), 
    $customSliderRight = $customSliderButtonRight.children().first(), 
    $customSliderPrevSlide = $customSliderLeft.children().next().next().children().first(),
    $customSliderNextSlide = $customSliderRight.children().next().next().children().first(), 
    $customSliderPage = $customSliderInner.next().next().next(),
    $customSliderTotalSlide = $customSlider.children().not($customSliderTimer,$customSliderInner,$customSliderPage).children().children().children().next().next(), 
    $customSlide = $customSliderInner.children(), 
    $customSlideContent = $customSlide.children().next().next(), 
    $customSlideContentInner = $customSlideContent.children(),
    $customSlideImage = $customSlide.children(':nth-child(1)'), 
    $customSlideVideo = $customSlideImage.children(), 
    $customSlidePlayer = $customSlideVideo.children(), 
    customSlideVideo = $customSlideVideo.attr('class'),
```

or like this:

```
var $innerDiv = $('#inner-container'),
    $customSlider = $('#custom-slider'),
    $customSliderInner = $('#custom-slider-inner'),
    $customSliderTimer = $('#custom-slider-timer'),
    $customSliderButtonLeft = $('.custom-slider-buttons-left'),
    $customSliderButtonRight = $('.custom-slider-buttons-right'),
    $customSliderLeft = $('.custom-slider-left'),
    $customSliderRight = $('.custom-slider-right'),
    $customSliderPrevSlide = $('.custom-slider-prevSlide'),
    $customSliderNextSlide = $('.custom-slider-nextSlide'),
    $customSliderPage = $('#custom-slider-pages'),
    $customSliderTotalSlide = $('.custom-slider-totalSlide'),
    $customSlide = $('.custom-slide'),
    $customSlideContent = $('.custom-slide-content'),
    $customSlideContentInner = $('.custom-slide-content-inner'),
    $customSlideImage = $('.custom-slide-image'),
    $customSlideVideo = $('.custom-slide-video'),
    $customSlidePlayer = $('.slidePlayer'),
    customSlideVideo = '.custom-slide-video',
```

and the html structure:

```
<div id="custom-slider">
        <div id="custom-slider-inner">      
            <div class="custom-slide">
                <div class="custom-slide-image" style="background-image:url(./sintel.png)">
                    <div class="custom-slide-video">
                        <video controls class="slidePlayer">
                        <source type="video/mp4" src="./sintel2.mp4" />
                        </video>
                    </div>                   
                </div>
                <div class="custom-slider-overlay" style="background-image:url(./images/pattern.png)"></div> 
                <div class="custom-slide-content">
                    <div class="custom-slide-content-inner left"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="custom-slide">
                <div class="custom-slide-image" style="background-image:url(./slide-5.png)">
                    <div class="custom-slide-video">
                        <video controls class="slidePlayer">
                        <source type="video/mp4" src="" />
                        </video>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="custom-slider-overlay" style="background-image:url(./images/pattern.png)"></div> 
                <div class="custom-slide-content">
                    <div class="custom-slide-content-inner left"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="custom-slide">
                <div class="custom-slide-image" style="background-image:url(./slide-4.jpg)"></div>
                <div class="custom-slider-overlay" style="background-image:url(./images/pattern.png)"></div> 
                <div class="custom-slide-content" style="color:#FFF">
                    <div class="custom-slide-content-inner right"></div>
                </div>     
            </div> 
        </div>  
        <div class="custom-slider-buttons-left">
            <div class="custom-slider-left">
                <div class="custom-slider-pagenb-overlay"></div>
                <i class="icon-angle-left"></i>
                <div class="custom-slider-left-pagenb">
                    <div class="custom-slider-prevSlide">1</div>
                    <div class="custom-slider-separator">/</div>
                    <div class="custom-slider-totalSlide">12</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="custom-slider-buttons-right">
            <div class="custom-slider-right">
                <div class="custom-slider-pagenb-overlay"></div>
                <i class="icon-angle-right"></i>
                <div class="custom-slider-right-pagenb">
                    <div class="custom-slider-nextSlide">10</div>
                    <div class="custom-slider-separator">/</div>
                    <div class="custom-slider-totalSlide">12</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="custom-slider-pages"></div>
        <div id="custom-slider-timer"></div> 
    </div>
```

Comment: Please post your HTML so we can see how best to traverse it. The first example will be quicker. You can use `siblings`, `find` etc. to remove the ugly chained function calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using the combination of both.
First one is faster, because it accesses the DOM just twice. The second one accesses the DOM on each variable.
But I would use something like:

```
...
$customSlider = $('#custom-slider'),
$customSliderInner = $customSlider.find('.custom-slider-inner'),
$customSliderTimer = $customSlider.find('.custom-slider-timer')
...
```

It looks more elegant and is better optimized if you decide to change internal structure of elements inside `#custom-slider`

Comment: _"First one is faster, because it accesses the DOM just twice."_ - Well that's not true: the `.children()` and `.next()` methods access the DOM too. But I agree with your suggestion about using `.find()` with a class, because the `.children().next().next().children()` stuff is completely unreadable.

Comment: I tried to mesure thanks `console.time('timerName')`. The second method seems faster (1ms) and the first (3ms) slower. But with the first I can change easly all class name of my slider but I agree thats ugly and confusing.

Comment: So, I should use .find()? In my case it's easy to use it because everything is a children of `$('#custom-slider')`